# <p></p> missing with wp_editor( get_option() );

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add some options to my theme and I added a wysiwyg textarea and the value of this textarea will go to the option table (wp-options).

So here is the code I used:

```
$settings = array(
  'textarea_name' => 'options[content]',
  'quicktags' => true,
  'tinymce'=> true,
);
wp_editor( get_option('content','default_value'), 'content', $settings );
```

This work pretty fine but this apparently remove all `<p>` tags from the content and i have absolutely no idea why..

For example when i wrote something like this:

```
Level 1 title
  Level 2 title
    a paragraph
    another paragraph
```

this is the code sent to the db called 'content':

```
<h1>Level 1 title</h1>
  <h2>Level 2 title</h2>
    a paragraph another paragraph
```

instead of this:

```
<h1>Level 1 title</h1>
  <h2>Level 2 title</h2>
    <p>a paragraph</p>
    <p>another paragraph</p>
```

Do you have any idea what i can do get unchanged value with all tags?

ps: when i add `<p>` tags manually to the text side, it works until I go back to the visual side and re-save.

Thanks for helping

Comment: You can use the `wpautop` function on your content.

Comment: And where do I use this? Because that add <p> on a string element but i don't have only string returned by content, i have h1 and h2!

Comment: Ok i got it: wpautop(get_option('content','default_value')); worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `wpautop` function on your content to add `<p>` tags around your paragraphs.

```
wp_editor( wpautop(get_option('content','default_value')), 'content', $settings );
```

Comment: I said it was solved but this is not exactly what i used.
This line was used on functions.php but i had to used: wpautop(get_option('content','default_value')); on the page where i called it.

Comment: Check this, there should be a hook, when admin edits the post / page: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/edit_post

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question that has had an accepted answer for some time but the answer didn't work for me, so I am adding the solution that did in case it helps anyone else.

I should explain that my problem was slightly different in that it was in the admin settings page of a plug-in, rather than a theme, but the principle should be the same. That is, in both cases the output from wp_editor needs to be stored in an option and later retrieved with paragraph tags intact.

The solution for me is based on the [Codex description of the wp_editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) and involves adding wpautop as an argument to the wp_editor call. Somewhat counter-intuitively, it needs to be set to `false` in order for paragraph tags to be added automatically. However, the original call to wpautop is also required to include the paragraph tags in the admin page.

```
$args = array(
  'wpautop' => false
);
wp_editor( wpautop( $content ), $editor_id, $args );
```

Comment: the accepted answer doesn't work, this answer works for me